# How to get Fragment value from url in Drupal 8?

Tags: uri

I need to get the Fragment value from url like: admin/config/system/meta_custom?query=test#abc=xyz in Drupal 8.

Need value of abc - ideally using Drupal's API, rather than doing my own Url Parsing.

Comment: I was looking for such answer and haven't found anything useful. Right now I'll use parse_url function from php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php, but if I find something in Drupal API I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

You could use it like this:

$path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
$arg  = explode('/',$path);

It gives:

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => node
    [2] => add
    [3] => application
)

Comment: \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo() only gets url and get params, but not fragments with #, so I think I does not the solution author looking for